# Cakephp Blog Tutorial error

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakephp. I followed this http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html tutorial, everything is working fine apart from the "edit method" when I click the edit link it gives following warning message and does not edit.

```
Warning (2): strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php, line 471]
Code Context
$type = array(
    (int) 0 => 'post',
    (int) 1 => 'put'
)
$this = object(CakeRequest) {
    params => array(
        'plugin' => null,
        'controller' => 'posts',
        'action' => 'edit',
        'named' => array([maximum depth reached]),
        'pass' => array(
            [maximum depth reached]
        )
    )
    data => array()
    query => array()
    url => 'posts/edit/2'
    base => '/cake_2_0'
    webroot => '/cake_2_0/'
    here => '/cake_2_0/posts/edit/2'
}
strtolower - [internal], line ??
CakeRequest::is() - CORE/Cake/Network/CakeRequest.php, line 471
PostsController::edit() - APP/Controller/PostsController.php, line 48
ReflectionMethod::invokeArgs() - [internal], line ??
Controller::invokeAction() - CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php, line 485
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 186
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php, line 161
[main] -
```

Comment: Post some of the code from the `PostsController.php` that should be inside the `function edit()`

Comment: public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid post'));
    }

    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
        $this->Post->id = $id;
        if ($this->Post->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been updated.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }

Comment: $this->Session->setFlash(__('Unable to update your post.'));
    }

    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $post;
    }
}

Comment: Code should go in the question! btw, please always mention your exact CakePHP version! (hint: the problem is related to the version you are using)

Comment: Thanks for the help it indeed concerns with the version. It actually solved my problem. I am using 2.2 version and following tutorial 2.4!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To clear this up a little further, it's the

```
$this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))
```

call causing the problem, as `CakeRequest::is()` has only been able to take an `array` as of CakePHP 2.4.0, earlier versions are expecting a `string`.

I'm not sure whether one should expect the tutorials to be compatible to older versions, however, for the sake of completeness, in older versions you'd have to use multiple calls to `CakeRequest::is()`:

```
$this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')
```

See also

- http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-CakeRequest.html#_is
- http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-CakeRequest.html#_is